# many movies in iOS app

Tags: ios, video, streaming, video-streaming, local

I am making an iOS app with about 40  15-20 second long videos (1 or 2 30 second ones)

Considering the size/quantity of them, I would like some advice/suggestions as to whether i should store them locally or steam them from online. I didn't want my app the require the internet for its main purpose.

Additionally, I think it would be useful if i knew exactly/the nature of what would be affected by having this size/quantity of videos...app performance? anything else negative?

And how would i test the performance myself if i tried to store them all locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1: 
Add them all to your project bundle and play them from bundle path.
Pro: After app installation everything works without network connection. Top performance. 
Con: Your app bundle will be larger. Every new version means user has to download them again and again (with the app).

Solution 2:
Stream them from server in realtime.
Pro: App bundle size is low.
Con: Videos are only available with a network connection. While playing it might stop to buffer if network quality is low. You can use Network Link Conditioner tool from Apple to test bad connections like Edge or with package loss.

Solution 3:
Download videos in app first (by user or automatically at first startup) and play them from filesystem.
Pro: App bundle size is low. Videos are playable without network connection and without buffering gaps. Top performance.
Con: Videos has to be downloaded first (with a network connection).